# Is it OK to return a string directly in C?

Tags: c, string, return-value

Trying to write a function which will return a string.

```
char *type(int type) {
    switch (type) {
        case 1: return "type 1";
        case 2: return "type 2";
        default: return "type 3";
    }
}
```

Is this the right way to return string? There is no space been allocated for the string by malloc or calloc. So, what's the lifecycle of them? Will the caller allocate new space to store the returned string?

Comment: "Return a string"? You are not returning a string here. You are returning a **pointer** to a string. `char *` is a pointer type.

Comment: @AnT pointer to a string or pointer to the first character in the string?

Comment: @Ajay Brahmakshatriya: Technically, it is a pointer to the first character in the string, as you said. However, the language standard itself explicitly defines what "a pointer to a string" means in **7.1.1 Definitions of terms**: "*A pointer to a string* is a pointer to its initial (lowest addressed) character". So, in standard parlance we just use the more concise shorter form: *a pointer to a string*.

Comment: @AnT Ah! I see. Learnt something new! Thanks. It just seems funny that the language defines 1. what a string is, 2. what a pointer to X is and separately defines 3.pointer to a string (something not consistent with combining 1 and 2).

Comment: Constant string literals like "type 1" are allocated at compile time, often in read-only memory, and therefore have a lifetime of the entire program. It's fine to return such a pointer--what it points to isn't going anywhere.

Comment: Note the use of `const` in the linked question. Also note that the caller must not free the string.